# simple task - pandas - df2 with numbers from df1 greater than ...

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a date column and numbers column (one number for each day). 
I want to create a new dataframe derived from this one with same columns (index dates) but only with numbers greater than 100.

how to create a new one with the same index (dates)

I'm a complete newbie in programming.
I tried different approaches I took from stackoverflow with loc , lambda, grouping etc and I was very 
df1.loc[df1['RANGE'] >= 150, 'AVG_HR']

Seems so simple but nothing works. Maybe its because I have python 2.7 ?

Comment: I think `df2 = df1[df1['RANGE'] >= 150]` should work.

Comment: or `df2 = df1.query("RANGE >= 150")`